# chef execute resource does not working on Rhel 8

Tags: resources, chef-infra, execute

I am using execute resource in cookbook recipe. the recipe is working  normaly while recipe calling on cli. the recipe does not working schedule with cron. i send error log below;

```
* execute[DNS Recording with Centrify] action run
    
    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[DNS Recording with Centrify]'
    ================================================================================
    
    Errno::ENOENT
    -------------
    No such file or directory - addns
    
    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/rhel8/recipes/centrify.rb
    
     48:                        execute 'DNS Recording with Centrify' do
     49:                                 command 'addns -U -m'
     50:                                user "root"
     51:                                 ignore_failure false
     52:                        end
     53:                end
    
    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/rhel8/recipes/centrify.rb:48:in `from_file'
    
    execute("DNS Recording with Centrify") do
      action [:run]
      default_guard_interpreter :execute
      command "addns -U -m"
      declared_type :execute
      cookbook_name "rhel8"
      recipe_name "centrify"
      domain nil
      user "root"
    end
```

i found the reason. the reason appear baceuse of different PATH. cookbook uses different PATH in the cli and in different cron. Mycommand binary in the cli PATH. i can not use static PATH because of cli PATH changes according to OS, verison and distribution.

how can set cli PATH in the cookbook according to all linux?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question it appears you want to have the respective `PATH` environment variable available for the `execute` resource.

You can try two options:

1. Set the environment variable `PATH` while executing command:

   ```rb
   execute 'DNS Recording with Centrify' do
     command 'addns -U -m'
     user 'root'
     environment(
       { 'PATH' => ENV['PATH'] }
     )
   end
   ```
2. Or use `default_env` property of resource to see if makes the `PATH` available:

   ```rb
   execute 'DNS Recording with Centrify' do
     command 'addns -U -m'
     user 'root'
     default_env true
   end
   ```